# How to set a Wifi lock without Android API?

Tags: android

I have a python service running on my rooted Android device (running Kit Kat 4.4) and I'm trying to find a way to set a [High Performance Wifi Lock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF) WITHOUT USING the Android API. The way I'm currently setting the wifi lock is through a custom-built [SL4A server](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/), which accesses the Android API.  I'd like to get away from doing this, if possible.

For example, I found that you can set a wake lock by modifying the file: **/sys/power/wake_lock**

Is there anything similar for wifi locks??

Comment: Have a look in /sys/android_wlan/wlan_power/

Comment: That directory is not there (at least on the device I'm using).  Your suggestion has given me some more leads to try though in the meantime.

Comment: No luck. Any other ideas?